# text-transform: uppercase causes layout error on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit, reflow

I've run across a strange layout bug that appears to be triggered by the `text-transform` CSS property when an `inline-block` is nested within a `block` element.  I saw the problem on Safari (5.1.2) as well, but this minimal test case only triggers on Chrome (17.0.963.56).

The particularly interesting bit is that opening the developer tools and keeping it on the Elements tab triggers the correct layout.  My best guess is that the combination of CSS rules and DOM structure is causing the webkit engine to miss performing a reflow of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu Widget Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container
            {
                border: 1px solid black;    
                display: inline-block;      
            }

            .title
            {   
                text-transform: uppercase; /* <-- Remove this and it works */
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = "John";
                document.getElementById("lastName").innerHTML = "Smith";
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>  <!-- Remove this DIV element, and it works -->
        <span class="container">
            <span class="title">
                <span id="firstName"></span>
                <span id="lastName"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here are two screenshots that show the two ways that it renders on Chrome, depending on whether or not the `text-transform` rule is removed, or the `div` element is removed.

[image: Bad rendering on the left, correct on the right]

I would like to use the `text-transform` property, but I am wondering if this is a known bug and what I can do to ensure that I do not trigger the behavior.  Even being able to explicitly trigger a reflow event might be good enough.

Comment: does the same thing happen if yopu dont use JS to write out the names?

Comment: I have copied the code you gave into a new html file that I put on the local wampserver and I opened it with chrome browser (17.0.963.56) and it works fine.

Comment: @Darko Z: No. That's why I didn't notice it for a while.  Putting content in the `firstName` and `lastName` spans renders capitalized text inside the bordered element.

Comment: @DawnUser: It doesn't show up in a JSFiddle either.  It appears to be sensitive to the surrounding DOM structure. If others can't reproduce it, I'll host it somewhere myself.

Comment: Can you upload the test case somewhere, and file a bug via http://new.crbug.com/  If you post the ID here, I'll throw it into the correct queue.

Comment: I've posted the test case at http://iigs.dreamhosters.com/code/test_MenuChrome.html.  I noticed that the test case is only failing on Chrome on 32-bit Windows 7.  The original problem shows up in Safari and on OS X, too.  I'll work on a more robust test case today before submitting to http://new.crbug.com..

Comment: I hit the same bug with one of my layout. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: Not yet.  Lots of false starts on finding a simple test case that doesn't depend on Dojo....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it with `white-space:nowrap;`.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a kind of race condition in the loading of css. The following file reproduces the bug here on Chrome (17.0.963.65) on osx 10.6.8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Schizophrenic layout</title> 
    <style type="text/css">
      body { background-image:url('gray.png'); }
      #d0{display:inline-block;}
      #d1{text-transform:uppercase;}
      #d2{text-transform:uppercase;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function fill (id, text)
      {
        var e = document.getElementById (id);
        var t = document.createTextNode (text); 
        e.appendChild (t);
      }

      function main () 
      {   
        fill ("d1", "First line");
        fill ("d2", "Second line"); 
      }
      window.onload = main;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="d0">
      <div id="d1"></div> 
      <div id="d2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the bug is present even if `gray.png` is not a 404. You may have to reload the page a few time to witness the bug. Also if you don't GET the file over http, the bug shows only once, the first time you load the page from the disk.

There are various ways to make the bug disappear by tweaking the css. Removing only the `background-image` makes it disappear. Removing only the `display` makes it disappear. Removing only the two `text-transform` make it disapear. In the latter case the correct layout can be achieved by adding

```
     e.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
```

at the end of the `fill` function which is, of course, a very ugly workaround.