# How to increase width of a span tag inside an li

Tags: css

I have a `ul` with the following structure

```
<ul>
    <li> text goes here <span></span> </li>
    <li> text goes here <span></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Now initially the span tag is empty. Im trying to add a number into the span tag using the jQuery `.html()` function ,Works fine however in Chrome the text gets cut off. The strange thing is when i use the web inspector and click on the li the width of the span tag increase according to the content and the li too.

Any ideas ?

The css is as follows

```css
li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

span{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:5px;
    min-height:5px;
}
```

Comment: would overflow:visible; work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't. `span` is an `inline` element, either set it's display property to `inline-block` or `block` to set its dimensions, or use a `block` element instead of `span`.

```
white-space: nowrap; // will force it not to wrap around
```

See effect on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Abp8y/11/ [UPDATED].

**Last diagnosis:** `text-transform` bug caught in the li tag. Removing `text-transform` solves the problem.

The Chrome bug is also discussed here: [text-transform: uppercase causes layout error on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422271/text-transform-uppercase-causes-layout-error-on-chrome) as posted by @Christoph

Comment: The span tag is declared as inline-block .Even if i were to use a div tag the width just does not increase in chrome till i click inspect element. On page refresh it works

Comment: @Neil try the `white-space: nowrap;` style in your span to force it not to wrap around when the content is too long.

Comment: Thanks Dexter , but that is not the problem .  The width of the span and the li does not increase when the text is added to the span tag . But on page refresh the li width increases to cover the text and the span tag

Comment: @Neil Can you show the actual problem thru a fiddle example? Update my fiddle as you wish.

Comment: @Neil last updated fiddle with an anchor, and a click event handler to add content to span on click: http://jsfiddle.net/Abp8y/6/

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle now in Chrome . When  the content is added it is initially hidden till  you click inspect element using the web inspector

Comment: @Neil the `text-transform` is the culprit. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Abp8y/11/

Comment: wow ! your right . But do you know why ? Because this works in all the other browsers perfectly .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422271/text-transform-uppercase-causes-layout-error-on-chrome

Comment: @Neil Am not sure why, but I think it manipulates the default style positioning when transforming the text within it.

Comment: @Neil So it is a bug, lmao. There is your answer as posted by Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Use can try this and fix the width of span-

```
span{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: word-wrap:break-word causes the text to wrap in the span block , The width of the span does not increase with the content ,Only when i click inspect element does it actually increase