# Chrome Display Bug with text wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The link "WHAT WE DO" in my main navigation does not display in full, the word 'DO' is cutoff. If you change the word "DO" to something else in the inspector, for example "WHAT WE ELEPHANT", it displays in full as it should. Certain other combinations are cutoff as well, for example if you try "WHAT WE PO" etc.

The site uses Bootstrap. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the issue, however I'm drawing blanks.

Comment: Is this a recent occurrence?

Comment: It is a recently built website and the issue has existed from the beginning. I'm just the unfortunate soul who has to do all the debugging.

Comment: Ah. I asked because I'm having a Chrome bug issue myself, but it started just today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that "What We Do" is wrapping "Do" to the next line.

I had success by adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the links inside the `<li>s`:

```
.main-nav a {
  ...
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

### Edit:

See this issue regarding `text-transform`, mentioned in the answer by Chris Laarman:
[text-transform: uppercase causes layout error on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422271/text-transform-uppercase-causes-layout-error-on-chrome)

Comment: True, but it doesn't explain why with "do" it doesn't work but works with "Elephant"

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still very curious, but the fix works so I'm happy.

Comment: See the Chrome text-transform issue mentioned by Chris Laarman. Definitely seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The code below seems to fix the problem

```
.main-nav a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you turn off the text-transform, you can see it displays all words on 1 line. So it seems that the text-transform comes after calculating the width. Not sure exactly why yet, but it seems to just push it over the edge

Link below seems to describe the same problem:

[text-transform: uppercase causes layout error on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422271/text-transform-uppercase-causes-layout-error-on-chrome)